# Mathematical Statement about Graph Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

> Statement: Let $G'$ be a non-connected subgraph of the connected graph
> $G$. Then there exists in $G$ an edge not belonging to $G'$, such that
> every cycle in $G$ containing this edge also contains at least one
> other edge not belonging to $G'$.
>
> Namely, let $A_1$ and $P$ be two such nodes in $G'$ that cannot be
> connected by a path in $G'$. However, in $G$, there must be a path
> from $A_1$ to $P$. Let $A_1A_2...A_n$ (where $A_n = P$) be such a
> path, and let it be chosen so that the number $v$ of edges that do not
> belong to $G'$ is minimal within this path. In this path, there is
> certainly an edge $A_iA_{i+1}$ that does not belong to $G'$. This edge
> corresponds to the statement. Otherwise, there would exist a cycle in
> $G$, $A_iA_{i+1}B_1B_2 ... B_mA_i$, in which only edges from $G'$
> appear besides $A_iA_{i+1}$. However, the sequence of edges $A_1A_2$
> $... A_{i-1}A_iB_mB_{m-1} ... B_1A_{i+1}A_{i+2} ... A_n$, and even more
> so, the path leading from $A_1$ to $A_n = P$ contained in this
> sequence, would have fewer than v such edges not belonging to $G'$.
> This contradicts the assumed minimality property of $v$.

I have a problem understanding this prove. In my eyes it only shows a contradiction of the assumptions. The first part shows, that there must be an edge outside $G'$ to connect two nodes that can't be connected inside $G'$ - meaning they are both in seperated subgraphs. Therefore there has to be an edge outside $G'$ to connect both nodes. However, the second part is not helping to prove the statement in my opinion. It only shows that $G'$ has to be a connected subgraph of $G$ to connect $A_1$ and $P$.

Why is this proof complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 0:** have a connected graph $G$, and a subgraph $G'$ of $G$ that is not connected.

At this point, $G$ and $G'$ are fixed, nailed in place, not going to change during the proof.

---

**Step 1:** because $G'$ is not connected, there are vertices $A_1, P$ in separate connected subgraphs of $G'$.

At this point, $A_1$ and $P$ are fixed, and not going to change for the entire duration of the proof (always going to be in different connected components of $G$).

---

Thus if you truly believe the proof shows "that $G'$ has to be a connected subgraph of $G$ to connect $A_1$ and $P$", this contradicts the setup above.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I read the prove. This is what I meant by "first part". But this doesn't prove the statement yet, does it? To prove that there is a cycle that contains another edge outside $G'$ you have to prove it by connecting $A_1$ and $P$ and $P$ and $A_1$. This is only possible with another edge outside $G'$.

Comment: If there is no other edge outside $G'$, then there are no cycles containing this edge, which is perfectly consistent with the statement.

Comment: Okay thank you. But where can you find this in the prove above? It's hard for me to understand their logic process to prove the statement using the contradiction.

Comment: I mean in the prove in my question not this answer.

Comment: “To prove that there is a cycle…” — the proof does not show that. The proof shows that ***IF there is*** a cycle in $G$ containing a certain edge in a certain path from $A_1$ to $P$, then that cycle must contain an edge not in $G’$. At no point are we trying to show there is a cycle.

Comment: But isn't this necessary to prove the statement? This is why I asked if this prove is complete.

Comment: The proof is complete. The statement is exactly as I described: “***IF there is*** a cycle in $G$ containing a certain edge (the edge the proof narrows in on), then that cycle must contain an edge not in $G’$”. That is the correct interpretation of the statement.